# Quantile loss 50th is MAE, is it?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, quantile-regression, mae

I'm not sure the above sentence is true, but I read it [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-c85481548b5a), [here](https://www.evergreeninnovations.co/blog-quantile-loss-function-for-machine-learning/) and [here](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/5-regression-loss-functions-all-machine-learners-should-know-4fb140e9d4b0) that quantile loss function percentile 0.5 is MAE (mean absolute error). Is it true (yes or no)? And How?

Comment: Perhaps "0.5" should be "50"?

Comment: I couldn't find out is it my answer,@S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 9):

Well mathematically speaking, quantile loss for quantile $\gamma$ is defined as:

$L_{\gamma}(y,y^p) = \sum_{i:y_i<\hat{y}_i}(1-\gamma)|y_i-\hat{y}_i| + \sum_{i:y_i\geq \hat{y}_i}(\gamma)|y_i-\hat{y}_i|$

For $\gamma=0.5$ (median), this becomes:

$L_{0.5}(y,y^p) = \sum_{i:y_i<\hat{y}_i}\frac{1}{2}|y_i-\hat{y}_i| + \sum_{i:y_i\geq \hat{y}_i}\frac{1}{2}|y_i-\hat{y}_i| = \sum\frac{1}{2}|y_i-\hat{y}_i|$

Considering that the MAE is:

$MAE = \frac{1}{n}\sum|y_i-\hat{y}_i|$

the two only differ by a constant, and they are therefore equivalent in terms of optimization.

Comment: according to the first equation, after replacing  0.5 in that, one of the coefficients is -0.5 and the second one is 0.5, and after summation, these coefficients disappear.

Comment: Sorry I corrected, It was $1-\gamma$ and not $\gamma -1$

Comment: I realized it might not have been clear - I just passed the two coefficients in fraction form because it was easier to compare to MAE

Comment: Can I use this loss to compare it with MAE?